# What is the meaning of と in this case

Tags: grammar, particle-と

This is one of the meanings according to https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18330

> 繰り返し・累加   一人、また一人と辞めていった

I found `一人また一人と` as an expression on https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=18330

I also found this example:

> １度だけじゃなく、２度、３度と失敗した

In this case, how does it function grammatically?

Is it equivalent to [Particle と after numbers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/96882/particle-%e3%81%a8-after-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically it should be the following ([#5](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8/#jn-154670)):

> （副詞に付いて新たな副詞をつくり）ある状態を説明する意を表す。「そろそろ―歩く」「そよそよ―風が吹く」

That is, it is making (2度)3度 an adverb.

In both examples, the と is optional. Below are fine as well. (In this sene, the と is redundant.)

> 繰り返し・累加 一人、また一人辞めていった
>
> １度だけじゃなく、２度、３度失敗した

So it is different from the one in the linked question (concrete number+と).

Comment: The one in the linked answer is also turning numbers in adverbs, but I agree with you about the rest.

Comment: @Manab You are right. Grammatically they are the same. I meant the one in the linked one cannot be omitted.